# CURL to POSTMAN

Tags: api, curl, http-headers, postman

```
$ curl https://api.blockscore.com/question_sets/536c1532627463780b000000/score \
  -u sk_test_n5049aa6053c9a0217bea78070fbf501: \
  --header "Accept: application/vnd.blockscore+json;version=4" \
  -d 'answers[][question_id]=1' \
  -d 'answers[][answer_id]=3' \
  -d 'answers[][question_id]=2' \
  -d 'answers[][answer_id]=2' \
  -d 'answers[][question_id]=3' \
  -d 'answers[][answer_id]=2' \
  -d 'answers[][question_id]=4' \
  -d 'answers[][answer_id]=2' \
  -d 'answers[][question_id]=5' \
  -d 'answers[][answer_id]=5'
```

how to set this parameters in getpostman?

what is  equivalent of `-u`, `--header`, `-d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Content-Type` in cURL is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In Postman, you can just select the <kbd>x-www-form-urlencoded</kbd> button and start typing in your key value pairs, i.e.

```
            Key                 Value
    answers[][question_id]         1
```

For `--header`, there's a <kbd>Headers</kbd> button at the top right. When you click it, you will see fields to type in header value pairs also. Just type `Accept` on the left, and the type value on the right.

```
          Header                       Value
          Accept     application/vnd.blockscore+json;version=4
```

The default authentication is [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for cURL. When you do `-u username`, you get prompted for the password. This is to protect against any shell storage of the password. You could alternatively use `-u username:password`, but this will store the password in the shell history, and is not recommended. Either way, cURL will set the `Authorization` header to `Basic base64encode(username:password)`.

You need to actually base64 encode `username:password`. There are online places you can do so, like [here](https://www.base64encode.org/). For example if you type in `username:password` then encode it, it will return `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`

So basically, in Postman, you should set a header `Authorization` as the name, then `Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` (that is if the username is `username` and the password is `password`). Yours will be different of course.

```
          Header                       Value
       Authorization       Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```